# Typescript i am getting TS2344 error when using interface, but switching to type declaration solves the problem, why?

Tags: typescript

I want you to explain me why this is happening?

In the code below i am getting **TS2344** error, but when i change **GroupCallEvents** declaration with "**type**" instead of "**interface**", the error disappears. Why?

TS version: 4.4.4

```
interface GroupCallEvents {
  audioToggled: (v: boolean) => void;
  videoToggled: (v: boolean) => void;
};

export class GroupCall extends BaseEntity<GroupCallEvents> {}

type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => void;
export class BaseEntity<Events extends Record<string, AnyFunction>> {}
```

[Code as Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kbE2.png)

[Code as Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN31W.png)

["Solved" version of code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAtK1.png)

Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, i have corrected the question.